# how do make hardware back button become exit app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I found this code but its for javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
       if($.mobile.activePage.is('#homepage')){
           e.preventDefault();
           navigator.app.exitApp();
       }
       else {
           navigator.app.backHistory()
       }
    }, false);
}
```

this case is like my case, that I want to make the back button become the exit way of my app when in certain page (in this case is /home) but this code is written in javascript, I want to make this in angularjs, how do I write it? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "exit app"? On Android and iOS applications do not have any kind of exit button.

Comment: is this AngularJs.. it seems to be using Jquery Mobile framework

Comment: if you are usng ui-router framework , check the state and exit the app..

Comment: @Dai what I mean is the function of back button become like home button, when user pressed back button is my home page, it will not go back history to previous opened page, but exit the app.

Comment: @Nirus how do I do that? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Angular is JavaScript. This code requires no modification to work with angular, you just need to add it to your app.

Comment: I doubt it will work. $.mobile.activePage is a jquery mobile object. Ok, angular is javascript, but it's not jquery mobile!

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code for illustration that uses **Angular ui-router framework** which is a standard now:

> Read the code comments for better understanding. Please modify the below to your needs. You have to call the exit code only when the cordova library is loaded. So call the angular initialization code inside `deviceready` event callback.

**Sample HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
    <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="angular-ui-router.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ui-view></div>
        <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Sample JS code: Call after the cordova is loaded inside deviceready**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider' , function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/page1")
    $stateProvider
    .state('page1', {             
          url: "/page1",
          template: '<div><div>{{topmsg}}</div><a  ui-sref="page2">Middle</a></div>',
          controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.topmsg = "loaded top!";
            console.log("Page 1");
          }
    })

    .state('page2', {             
          url: "/page2",
          template: '<div>{{topmsg}}</div>',
          controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.topmsg = "Pages 2";
            console.log("Page 2");
          }
    });        
}])

.run(function($rootScope, $state){
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){
        console.log("state - "+ toState.name);
            //debugger;
        if(toState.name == "page2"){
            //Add Your closing code here
            //navigator.app.exitApp();
        }       
    }); 
});
```

**Explaination:**

I have created two pages. Just for illustration while navigating to the second page i am closing the app by calling `navigator.app.exitApp()`.

Refer this [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) for parameters that are available on stage change event.

**Note:** iOS Appstore rejects your app if you quit the app from code.