# How to take the last value in certain property from JSON in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, json, cordova

I have this code in my app.js for send chat and read chat in my application

```
$scope.messageshistory = {};
$scope.tmp = {};

    // send message
    $scope.sendMessage = function(){
        $scope.messages = {
            from      : $scope.datauser['data']['_id'],
            fromname  : $scope.datauser['data']['nama'],
            to        : $scope.tmpuserid,
            message   : $scope.tmp['sendmessage'],
            time      : moment()
        };
          //event emit message
        socket.emit('message',$scope.messages,function(callback){       
          if(!callback['error']){
                 $scope.messages['time'] = moment($scope.messages['time']).format('DD-MMMM-YYYY HH:MM');


                if ($scope.messageshistory.hasOwnProperty($scope.tmpuserid)){ //yg di json yg paling awal
                    $scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid].push($scope.messages);
                }else{
                    $scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid] =   [];
                    $scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid].push($scope.messages);
                }
                $scope.tmp['sendmessage'] = '';
          }else{
               var msg = callback['error'];
                navigator.notification.alert(msg,'','Error Report', 'Ok');
            }

            $scope.$apply();
        });
    };
      //event read message
    socket.on('message', function (data) {

        window.plugin.notification.local.add({
            id        :   moment(),
            title     :   data['fromname'],
            message   :   data['message'].substr(0,20) + ' ...',
            led       : 'A0FF05',
            json      :   JSON.stringify({ routes:'chat', nama :data['fromname'],from:data['from'] })
        });
        data['time'] = moment(data['time']).format('DD-MMMM-YYYY HH:MM');
        if ($scope.messageshistory.hasOwnProperty(data['from'])){
            $scope.messageshistory[data['from']].push(data);
        }else{
            $scope.messageshistory[data['from']] =   [];
            $scope.messageshistory[data['from']].push(data);
        }

        for(var i = 0; i<= $scope.datauser['data']['friends'].length; i++){
            if($scope.datauser['data']['friends'][i]['userid'] == data['from']){
                $scope.datauser['data']['friends'][i]['ischat'] = true;
                break;
            }
        };
        $scope.$apply();
    });
```

my question is **how to take the last value in message property** from `$scope.messageshistory`, because `$scope.messages` is for sending the message and `$scope.messageshistory` is to keep the chat history. This is the chat activity image:

[image]

just from this activity, `$scope.messageshistory` will save the data in it JSON as:

```
{
    "5512": [{
        "from": "561c",
        "fromname": "ryan",
        "to": "5512",
        "message": "hey",
        "time": "18-Maret-2016 21:03"
    }, {
        "from": "5512",
        "fromname": "sasa",
        "to": "561c",
        "message": "hello",
        "time": "18-Maret-2016 21:03",
        "_id": "593s"
    }]
}
```

I get this value from using `angular.toJson($scope.messageshistory)`, and this array will always add up if the chat activities still going on. And my intention to get the last value in message property from `$scope.messageshistory`is to use in Text-to-Speech feature in my application. This is the code:

```
$scope.speakText = function() {

    TTS.speak({
           text: **this the place for the code**,
           locale: 'en-GB',
           rate: 0.75
       }, function () {
          // handle the success case
       }, function (reason) {
           // Handle the error case
       });
  };
```

it will read the last message in `$scope.messageshistory`. So, what code that I must write to take the last value?

Comment: looks like `$scope.messageshistory` is an object. You want to get the latest message for a specific userId key?, or the latest message emitted by socket? What about `$scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid][$scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid].length-1]`?

Comment: @cl3m wait I will try it

Comment: @cl3m it work, but its still all property, how to just take the 'message' property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the following:

```
var msgs = $scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid]
var yourLastMessage = msgs[msgs.length-1].message
// you could also add a quick check so you don't get
// an error if the messages array is emtpy :
// var yourLastMessage = (msgs && msgs[msgs.length-1] ? msgs[msgs.length-1].message : null)
```

**Edit**

Some explanation per your comment :

```
var msgs = $scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid]
// msgs is now an Array containing Objects
// [{message : 'xxx'},{message : 'yyy'}]
// we take the last entry of the msgs Array (msgs.length-1)
// so msgs[msgs.length-1] is the last object ({message : 'yyy'})
// and finally we take the 'message' property' of that object:
var yourLastMessage = msgs[msgs.length-1].message
```

Comment: its work like a charm, thanks for your answer. Last question, so better I write `var yourLastMessage = (msgs && msgs[msgs.length-1] ? msgs[msgs.length-1].message : null)` or just `var yourLastMessage = msgs[msgs.length-1].message` ?

Comment: Since you are always pushing a value in your array (`$scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid].push($scope.messages);`), You can reasonably skip the test

Comment: can you take a look to my previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811385/how-do-make-hardware-back-button-become-exit-app if you dont mind it. In that question I want to make the back button hardware is become an exit app when user in `home` page. thanks

Comment: There is already a lot of good answers to your previous question. Have you tried them? Can you post a bit more html code, specially the back `<button>` tag, as well as your angular controller?

Comment: I am so sorry to ask this, but can you explain why this is working? thanks mate :D

Comment: thanks a lot, u help me. last question, what about this `$scope.messageshistory[$scope.tmpuserid]` ?

Comment: Looks like you are taking a list of all messages for a certain user : `$scope.tmpuserid` is the identifier of a user, and `$scope.messageshistory` looks like an object whose keys are user ids and values are lists of user messages

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the keys in the history object are ascending numbers and taking into account that the order of keys in an object is not specified by W3C you will have to do the following:

1. get all keys
2. find the "latest" (hence the biggest number)
3. fetch it

so you could do for example

```
var keys = Object.keys($scope.messagehistory);
keys.sort (function (a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
var result = keys[keys.length - 1];
```